# How can I use variables defined later in the page? PHP

Tags: php

This is how I have my files setup:

INDEX.PHP:

```
    include($sys->root_path.'sections/start.php'); // Includes everything from <html> to where we are now

    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
      $page = $_GET['page'].'.php';
    } else {
      $page = 'index.php';
    }

    if (isset($_GET['cat'])) {
      $cat = $_GET['cat'];
    } else {
      $cat = '';
    }

    include($sys->root_path.'/content/'.$cat.'/'.$page);

    include($sys->root_path.'sections/end.php'); // Includes everything from here to </html>
```

To view this page, I visit: `example.com/index.php?cat=red&page=car`
This will show me a page with the content of the file at:

```
/content/red/car.php
```

The problem I am having is that I want to specify a title, meta description, etc. for each page, and this is outputted to the page in `start.php`- before any specific data for this particular page is called.

What I was hoping to do is something like this:

/CONTENT/RED/CAR.PHP:

```
<?php $page_title = 'Title of the page'; ?>
<p>Everything below is just the page's content...</p>
```

How can I use this page specific data in the `<head>` of the site, when all that data is grabbed before the contents of this specific page?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do that. You need to remove the `<head>` tag from one of the two files because if you echo it twice, the browser gets it twice.

Comment: ... or use output buffering, which, while it would work, is almost definitely not the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
switch($_GET['page']) {
    case 'car':
        // Here you could have another conditional for category.
        $page_title = 'Title of the page';
        break;
    // Other cases.
}
include($sys->root_path.'sections/start.php');
```

And in start.php you could have something like:

```
<title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
```

I must advise against that way of including content.  It is insecure.  Someone could browse your server files or include something you don't want included.  One should never include files that way (through get variables) unless one always filter that variable through a regular expression or something else.

Answer (score 1):

> The correct way to do what you're trying to do is with a database and
>   apache url_rewrite. My answer is just a ***fix*** for your problem.

---

## Step 1

Include `start.php` below the `if statment`, this way when you include start.php you already know which page you need, like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
  $page = $_GET['page'].'.php';
} else {
  $page = 'index.php';
}

if (isset($_GET['cat'])) {
  $cat = $_GET['cat'];
} else {
  $cat = '';
}

include($sys->root_path.'sections/start.php');
```

## Step 2

Now, inside the `start.php` use a switch:

```
<?php
switch ($cat) {
    case "blue":
        $title = "The car is $page";
        break;
    case "green":
        $title = "The car is $page";
        break;
    case "red":
        $title = "The car is $page";
        break;
    default:
        $title = "Welcome to ...";
} 
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
    </head>
etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I want to keep all the page-specific data on that page. I don't want to have to go updating multiple pages. And, this site may have several hundred pages. It's not practical to use a switch statement for all of that, or to specify each page title separately like that. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use an MVC approach with either a function to pass the parameters or OOP with a setter function.